# How to use react-redux in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new in ReactJs. Please help me to find some helping material in which I find some good stuff of reactJs with redux in Visual Studio 2015.

I am facing problem when I include redux and try to use

```
Import {createstore} from 'redux'
```

But I get an error

> Cannot find module redux

Answer (score 1):

```
Import {createstore} from 'redux'
```

needs to be

```
import {createStore} from 'redux'
```